# How can i delete certain lines in R?

Tags: r, filter, linear-regression

I want to delete line 1 to 94875 in my dataset (global terrorism database - kaggle) so that I can just work with the attacks between 2010 and 2017.
Furthermore, I want to summarize/count all lines with the same year -> so in the end I can do a linear regression about the increase of attacks over the years.

```
dplyr::filter(globalterrorismdb_0718dist, grepl('1970', iyear))
```

I already tried this to filter the lines but won´t help me to move on.

Comment: you mean `globalterrorismdb_0718dist[-c(1:94875), ]` ?

Comment: Or you could just use filter for the years you are interested in.

Comment: @Ronak Shah yea exaclty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also just do it directly on the dataframe:

```
# this will overwrite your existing dataframe...

# select only entries from row 94876 to end of table
your_df <- your_df[94876:nrow(your_df),]

# filter for timerange
your_df <- your_df[(your_df$iyear >= 2010 & your_df$iyear <= 2017),]
```

If you rename `your_df` next to `<-` you'll instead create a new dataframe with the same properties

Comment: how do i save it? that it won´t jump back to the common dataframe

Comment: you can either overwrite your existing dataframe or create a new one.. I'll adjust my answer

Comment: ok, that worked well! Now i saved each year between 2000 and 2017 with it´s own variable. How can i create a plot which has on the y-axis the number of attacks and on the x-axis the years? (i choosed from 2000-2017 the variables a-r)

Comment: thats the code: >gf_point(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r~iyear, data = globalterrorism)

Comment: That really depends on the kind of plot you are aiming for - easiest being `plot(df)`. This should rather be a separate question however.